# find the index of a char at string

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code prints the string with upper case for every even number.
I checked the index of every charactr by the index counter (index = 0). 
Is there another option to find the index ? without creatine index count ?

```py
def myfunc(str):
    index = 0
    low = str.lower()
    new_str = ''
    for char in str:
        if index % 2 == 0:
            new_str += char.upper()
        else:
            new_str += char
        index += 1
    return new_str

print(myfunc('Hello World'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def myfunc(s):
    return ''.join(map(''.join, zip_longest(s[::2].upper(), s[1::2], fillvalue='')))

print(myfunc('Hello World'))
```

Output:

```
HeLlO WoRlD
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of enumerate object.

**Ex.**

```
def myfunc(str):
    new_str = ''
    for index,char in enumerate(str):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            new_str += char.upper()
        else:
            new_str += char
    return new_str

print(myfunc('Hello World'))
```

**O/P:**

```
HeLlO WoRlD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(str_string):  #  Dont use the str, its a keyword
    str_string = str_string.lower()
    new_str = ''
    for index in range(len(str_string)):  # loop through the string length rather string itself
        if index % 2 == 0:
            new_str += str_string[index].upper()
        else:
            new_str += str_string[index]
        index += 1
    return new_str

print(myfunc('Hello World'))


# one liner
str_index = 'Hello World'
print("".join([str_index[i].upper() if i%2==0 else str_index[i].lower() for i in range(len(str_index))  ]))
```